# refundRequestSheet done button is not working properly [SwiftUI 4, iOS16.1+]

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios16

I am having an issue with `refundRequestSheet`. So basically, my issue is that everything is presented just fine, I can get through the refund process, but at the end of the process where we are having done button, after I press the done button nothing is happening, result is not being called - it looks like the button is not actually calling any action.

The only way for me to close the screen is to actually swipe the sheet down, and then the result of `onDismiss` sometimes is failure and sometimes is a success.

I also investigated other type of sheets such `manageSubscriptionsSheet`, and this is having the same issue basically.

I also tried both simulator and the actual device, still nothing.

```
.refundRequestSheet(for: viewModel.transactionID ?? 0, isPresented: $viewModel.showRefundSheet, onDismiss: { _ in
viewModel.showRefundSheet = false
 })
```

Comment: Seeing the same issue - did you ever find a fix?